Getting solution items from Visual Studio solution (.sln) file
I am using SolutionFile.Parse from Microsoft.Build.Construction (Microsoft.Build package version 17.10.4) to extract project information, but I also need to get solution items e.g. packages.props files. I can see that they occupy a "Solution Items" folder in the Visual Studio solution, but the parsed SolutionFile object doesn't contain this information; although a SolutionFolder object representing that portion of the solution is present, the list of files as they appear in Visual Studio aren't represented in the parsed object. What is the best approach to get at these details programmatically?

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/1708

This may be a good example to get solution items information:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string solutionPath = @"C:\Users\SolutionItems\SolutionItems.sln"; //change to your path
            if (!File.Exists(solutionPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Solution file not found: {solutionPath}");
                return;
            }
            string[] solutionLines = File.ReadAllLines(solutionPath);
            Regex projectRegex = new Regex(@"Project\(""{[^}]+}""\)\s+=\s+""[^""]+"",\s+""[^""]+"",\s+""[^""]+""");
            Regex solutionItemsRegex = new Regex(@"^\s*GlobalSection\(SolutionItems\) = preSolution$");
    
            List<string> solutionItems = new List<string>();
            bool inSolutionItemsSection = false;
    
            foreach (string line in solutionLines)
            {
                if (solutionItemsRegex.IsMatch(line))
                {
                    inSolutionItemsSection = true;
                    continue;
                }
    
                if (inSolutionItemsSection)
                {
                    if (line.Trim().StartsWith("EndGlobalSection"))
                    {
                        inSolutionItemsSection = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    var match = Regex.Match(line.Trim(), @"^(?<file>[^=]+)\s*=\s*(?<path>.+)$");
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        var file = match.Groups["file"].Value.Trim();
                        var path = match.Groups["path"].Value.Trim();
                        solutionItems.Add(path);
                    }
                }
                else if (projectRegex.IsMatch(line))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Solution Items:");
            foreach (var item in solutionItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }


I was in the process of falling back to a RegEx-based parsing approach, so I take it that there is no Microsoft-provided or Microsoft-endoresed package for this purpose

I came up with the following; not entirely sure about how selective or permissive my regex will be, but appears to do the job:
    static readonly Regex SolutionItemsRegex = new Regex(@"ProjectSection\(SolutionItems\)[^\n]+(\s*(?<File>[\S|\x20]+)\s*=\s*(?<Path>[\S|\x20]+)\s*)*EndProjectSection", RegexOptions.Singleline);

    static IEnumerable<string> GetSolutionItems(string solutionFile)
    {
        var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFile);
        var solutionText = File.ReadAllText(solutionFile);

        var matches = SolutionItemsRegex.Matches(solutionText);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            var group = match.Groups["Path"];
            foreach (Capture capture in group.Captures)
            {
                yield return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(folder, capture.Value.Trim()));
            }
        }
    }

